# Combinatorics Application Question - Ordering with Color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have had trouble solving the following problem:

**How many ways are there to write five 1's and four 0's, each colored in it's own color, in a string, if no two 0's are allowed next to each other?**

I assume this involves permutations given that we must order the 1's and 0's so that no two 0's are allowed next to each other. I would greatly appreciate a solution and the necessary steps.

Comment: To speak of "0's and 1's"  first, and then of "different colours" seems like a redundant description to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First ignore the colors and find the number of ways to put the $1$s and $0$s in a row with no two zeros next to each other.  You should be able to do that by hand.  Otherwise, break into cases depending on whether you end with a $0$.  If you don't, attach a $1$ to the right of each $0$ and order four $01$s and a single $1$.  If you do...  Then how many ways to assign colors to the $1$s?  To the $0$s?